# How to extract data from website to Google Sheet

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
<div class="ranktitle rank20'>Diamond</div>
<div class="rankinfo">   <b> 4489</b>
```

I tried to create a Google Sheet that can auto update, yet I struggled to extract "diamond" and "4489" from the website https://tabstats.com/siege/player/anson-na/4b6dc00d-8199-4a7f-a0f0-bd81cd272ee7

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126329/186471

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I have tried it before I post the question, yet it showed N/A. Any reason for that? And how am I supposed to solve it?